Place two sideway Tables next to each other on one side
Hello I have two sideway tables that I want to put next to each other it should look like:

The code I have is as follows:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}                  %H-Figure Typ
\usepackage[labelfont={bf,sf},font={small},%
  labelsep=space]{caption} 
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}
\Blindtext


\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \scriptsize 
    \caption{sfisjdsjosfjsofjisfj}
    \label{tab:meascore}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Identification}}  &  \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Sampling} }& \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{Measurements MC-ICP-MS} }  \\ \hline
        Nr. & Cruise & ID & DOI & Lat & Long & Methode & depht & Filter Dia & 18O NC & 18O C & 18O HC & 18O NC & 18O C & 18O HC \\ \hline
        ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & [cm] & [µm] & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{ vs VPDB }  \\ \hline       
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}


\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \scriptsize 
    \caption{sfisjdsjosfjsofjisfj}
    \label{tab:meascore}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Identification}}  &  \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Sampling} }& \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{Measurements MC-ICP-MS} }  \\ \hline
        Nr. & Cruise & ID & DOI & Lat & Long & Methode & depht & Filter Dia & 18O NC & 18O C & 18O HC & 18O NC & 18O C & 18O HC \\ \hline
        ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & [cm] & [µm] & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{ vs VPDB }  \\ \hline       
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\Blindtext

\end{document}



Furthermore I can't fix the tables with [H] in the text (between the two blindtexts) where I want it.

The code in your question does not compile

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz sorry I made it to minimalistic now it should work :) Thank you :)

If you like to have both tables on the same page, insert both in one sidewaystable environment.

hi that works :)

@Zarko how can I fixate the table between the two blindtextes?

Let me spell out my comment.
If I correctly understand you, you like to have both tables in the same page, something like this:

For this you need to insert both tables in one sideways environment and pout between them some vertical space, for example \bigskipor\vspace{2em}` if you like to have bigger vertical distance between table.
You should be aware, that sidewaystable always star at new page (following the point of its insertion in the text, as you can see in above picture.
Possible MWE:
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{float}                  % not needed in this MWE
\usepackage[labelfont={bf,sf},font={small},%
  labelsep=space]{caption} 
\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{wrapfig}               % not needed in this MWE
%\usepackage{gensymb}               % not needed in this MWE
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}
\Blindtext

\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \scriptsize 
    \caption{sfisjdsjosfjsofjisfj}
    \label{tab:meascore}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Identification}}  &  \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Sampling} }& \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{Measurements MC-ICP-MS} }  \\ \hline
        Nr. & Cruise & ID & DOI & Lat & Long & Methode & depht & Filter Dia & 18O NC & 18O C & 18O HC & 18O NC & 18O C & 18O HC \\ \hline
        ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & [cm] & [µm] & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{ vs VPDB }  \\ \hline       
    \end{tabular}

\vspace{4em}
    \caption{sfisjdsjosfjsofjisfj}
    \label{tab:meascore}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Identification}}  &  \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Sampling} }& \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{Measurements MC-ICP-MS} }  \\ \hline
        Nr. & Cruise & ID & DOI & Lat & Long & Methode & depht & Filter Dia & 18O NC & 18O C & 18O HC & 18O NC & 18O C & 18O HC \\ \hline
        ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & [cm] & [µm] & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{ vs VPDB }  \\ \hline       
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\bfseries\Blindtext

\end{document}

Addendum:
From you comment follows, that you like with table to interrupt text flow (with other worth: to remove one of the most desired features of (La)TeX). This can be od on tow ways:

after \end{sidewaystable} inser command clearpage˛
instead of sidewaystable use \landscape` environment:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[labelfont={bf,sf},font={small},
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage{pdflscape}     % when you like to have automatically rotated
                            % landscape pages for more convenient readin
                            % on the screen  

\begin{document}
\Blindtext

\begin{landscape}
    \centering
    \scriptsize 
    \captionof{figure}{sfisjdsjosfjsofjisfj}
    \label{tab:meascore}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Identification}}  &  \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Sampling} }& \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{Measurements MC-ICP-MS} }  \\ \hline
        Nr. & Cruise & ID & DOI & Lat & Long & Methode & depht & Filter Dia & 18O NC & 18O C & 18O HC & 18O NC & 18O C & 18O HC \\ \hline
        ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & [cm] & [µm] & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{ vs VPDB }  \\ \hline       
    \end{tabular}

\vspace{4em}
    \captionof{figure}{sfisjdsjosfjsofjisfj}
    \label{tab:meascore}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Identification}}  &  \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Sampling} }& \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{Measurements MC-ICP-MS} }  \\ \hline
        Nr. & Cruise & ID & DOI & Lat & Long & Methode & depht & Filter Dia & 18O NC & 18O C & 18O HC & 18O NC & 18O C & 18O HC \\ \hline
        ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & [cm] & [µm] & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{ vs VPDB }  \\ \hline       
    \end{tabular}
\end{landscape}

\Blindtext
\end{document}

Both cases gives similar, to my opinion very ugly, result:

Edit:
Package pdflscape automatically rotate landscapepage that can be more easy read on screen. If you not like to have this features of package and rather turn your head at reading of tables, than instead it just userlscape` package as it is noted now in MWE and showed on image.

Thank you, but I would like the first blind text to be before the tables and the second blind text after the tables and not in between as is currently the case. Normally you solve this with a [!ht] or [H] but somehow it doesn't work.

then I will mark yours as accapted :)

Than you should  insert clearpage after \sidewaystable environment. This will do what you after, but to my opinion result will be very ugly (a lot of empty space before \sidewaystable ). Another possibility is use of landscape environment (see edited answer)

Thank you so much! However when I use your ladscape command the Page is at the correct position but turned around 90 degree. How can I correct this?

When you print document, it is correct oriented. That bi be rotated on the screen, just use lscape instead pdflscape package (which automatically turn presentation of page for more convenient reading).

Hi thank you which will be the commends to use because with \begin{lscape} I got an error :)

Instead of starting a new sidewaystable environment, just use the same one and add some space between your tables:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}                  %H-Figure Typ
\usepackage[labelfont={bf,sf},font={small},%
  labelsep=space]{caption} 
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}
\Blindtext


\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \scriptsize 
    \caption{sfisjdsjosfjsofjisfj}
    \label{tab:meascore}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Identification}}  &  \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Sampling} }& \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{Measurements MC-ICP-MS} }  \\ \hline
        Nr. & Cruise & ID & DOI & Lat & Long & Methode & depht & Filter Dia & 18O NC & 18O C & 18O HC & 18O NC & 18O C & 18O HC \\ \hline
        ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & [cm] & [µm] & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{ vs VPDB }  \\ \hline       
    \end{tabular}
    \bigskip
    \caption{sfisjdsjosfjsofjisfj}
    \label{tab:meascorea}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Identification}}  &  \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Sampling} }& \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{Measurements MC-ICP-MS} }  \\ \hline
        Nr. & Cruise & ID & DOI & Lat & Long & Methode & depht & Filter Dia & 18O NC & 18O C & 18O HC & 18O NC & 18O C & 18O HC \\ \hline
        ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & [cm] & [µm] & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{ vs VPDB }  \\ \hline       
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\Blindtext

\end{document}


You just spell out my comment?

@Zarko seems so

@Zarko No, you didn't show how to add space between them to make them look look like separate tables.
